# What is /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o?

Tags: c++

So, I'm running a CPU scheduling smulation code but I came across a few errors while compiling

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)) /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::cout                           /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::close() /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::ios_base::Init::~Init()        /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::ios_base::Init::Init()         /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator!() const /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
__gxx_personality_v0                /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&) /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors and what is     `/var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o`?

Almost all the errors have it.

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question.

Comment: This is probably related to the simulation software. I mean does it generate source files in the /var/tmp folder?

Comment: I'm using Putty (Unix) to compile and I don't have access to the /var/tmp to check

Comment: @SPLASH: Of course you have access to `/var/tmp`. You have a shell. `cd`, `ls` and so on are your friend. That being said, this is not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why I'm getting these errors

Your program tries to use something that's part of an external library or a different object file, but you're not passing that to the linker as well.

> and what is /var/tmp//ccz0ct2G.o?

A temporary object file, that contains intermediate data that's going to be used in later stages of the compilation process.

Let me guess: You tried to compile with a command that went something like

```
g++ somesource.cc
```

You see, compilation consists of several stages:

```
1. compiling the individual source files (`*.c`, `*.cc` and so on) into *object files* (`*.o`).
2. linking the produced object files together into the actual program or library
```

When you call the compiler like you did, this is a shorthand that does both operations from a single call. But for the sake of simplicity and also because object files can grow rather large and it can pose a problem to keep them all in memory, the result of compiling the source file is placed into a temporary object file. That's what you have there.

Comment: As soon as you said library I slapped myself.  I went back and checked the libraries I found that I'm missing 'conio.h'. It didn't solve all the errors but it did remove some of them. Thanks buddy I will try to solve the other errors before posting another question XD